# OpenWrt LUCI run UI only

Tags: openwrt, luci

I have to modify the UI of OpenWrt LUCI. I'm an UX developer & don't want to build system packages every-time to test the dev work. Is there a way to run LUCI only so we can modify the UI code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

https://github.com/lisaac/luci-in-docker

It's base on luci 21.02